# Eclipse + git : clone over ssh not working

Tags: linux, eclipse, git, ssh

I've just installed Eclipse for `PHP` (Luna).

I'm trying to have the IDE to clone a git repository (bare) from URI.

So I did :

```
File > Import... > Projects from Git > Clone URI
```

First weird thing is I can't use `SSH` as the protocol (although it's in the list), and I need to use `SFTP` otherwise Eclipse says it can't connect.

I've given an URI of this type :

```
sftp://my_user@my_server_ip/path/to/my/repo.git
```

Then I selected my branches (tried selecting one or more master / HEAD)

Defined destination path, tried to check or uncheck `Clone submodules`.

Then it starts cloning.
Everything seems fine, until I get this error :

> Git repository clone failed.
>
> Cannot download 3d4d4abed8044e6d20c70ff4053e8af30713f0fe

Hitting the "Details >>" Button doesn't help more and basically says the same thing.

Now when I go to my destination folder I have nothing but the `.git` folder with `objects` and `refs`.

I thought maybe a data file was too big or something, so I checked on my server :

```
cd /path/to/my/repo.git
find ./ -name *3d4d4abed8044e6d20c70ff4053e8af30713f0fe*
# this outputs nothing, but taking a part of the hash :
find ./ -name *44e6d20c70ff4053*
# outputs : ./objects/3d/4d4abed8044e6d20c70ff4053e8af30713f0fe
```

Which seems absolutely weird to me because that's the exact same hash except for the few first characters :

```
3d4d4abed8044e6d20c70ff4053e8af30713f0fe
  4d4abed8044e6d20c70ff4053e8af30713f0fe
```

And magically, these non-matching chars are "3d" which is the name of the folder containing the binary file.

I've tried cloning the project with a linux box :

```
git clone ssh://user@ip/path/to/project.git
```

It worked like a charm.

I've tried to clone another git repository (non-bare) with Eclipse, and this it asked me for my password, which I gave and then it said it couldn't connect to the server (?!) (I've tried giving a wrong password, and in this case it asks again for the password).

```
URI : sftp://my_user@my_server_ip/path/to/my/second_repo.git
ERROR : "An error occured when trying to contact sftp://....../second_repo.git. Possible reasons : Incorrect URL
```

And again, this exact same URI (except I replaced `sftp` with `ssh`) worked fine on a linux box.

```
cd /tmp/
git clone ssh://my_user@my_server_ip/path/to/my/second_repo.git
>> Cloning into second_repo
>> ...
```

Any idea on what to do from there?

I don't get why one project starts to checkout and for the other (which is on the same server but is just "non-bare") a connection error happens?

Alternatively, could anyone point me an IDE supporting PHP, HTML, JS, and Git ? (please do it as a comment, not an answer unless it's really elaborated).

Thank you.

**EDIT :**

I have my answer to my second question : to clone, EGit is looking for an "objects" folder in the remote repository, so obviously that couldn't work with a "non-bare" repo.

Comment: Can you enter an ssh url in the "Clone git rpeository" dialog box, and *then* select git+ssh? (http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/Remote), and also load your existing ssh keys in the "Key management" tab?

Comment: Make it work from the command line first.

Comment: @VonC in the documentation you linked there is a "git+ssh" protocol, I haven't this, though others all are here.

Comment: Do you have ssh at least? And did you put an ssh url first?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen It works fine from the command line (using git bash I'm on win7), though I'm tired of notepad++ and wanted another IDE.

Comment: You can clone/push/pull from the command line, and do the rest in Eclipse.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I know right? But I'd have loved to be able to use git from the IDE and keep the terminal for special interventions. If nobody has a solution I guess I'll disappointingly head for that.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with Eclipse Luna 64-bit for Java, so i downgraded to Kepler, please give it a try and let me know if it helps.

[image: ,]

Answer (score -1):

In my case the proble was the url. Because not was a project git. Example

I was trying with : https://github.com/pkainulainen/spring-mvc-test-examples/tree/master/controllers-unittest

but the previous link was wrong, because was son of the father project

the father proyect was: https://github.com/pkainulainen/spring-mvc-test-examples

Comment: Your answer is not clear at all. Could you develop a little? And being given the experience of the guy asking, I think its not the issue..